# How to improve a look of a 2d light?

Tags: opengl, glsl, 2d, light

I'd like to have a nice light. I am not sure how exactly should I call it, but you'll see when I actually show some example.

What I mean by nice is like this scene:

[image]

It looks like light has some area and it ends somewhere.

What I tried to do is to calculate distance from current pixel to a light position and use the distance as a light, it does not look good at all

[image]

My last shot was to try 3d lightning techniques. I defined a normal for the scene which is `vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` and calculated a point light

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;  

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
};

vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 fragPos)
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + 
                 light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient;
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff;

    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;

    return ambient + diffuse;
}
```

doing light like so:

```cpp
    PointLight light;
    light.position = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.005f);
    light.constant = 0.5f;
    light.linear = 0.09f;
    light.quadratic = 0.032f;
    light.ambient = vec3(0.1f);
    light.diffuse = vec3(0.8f);

    vec3 result = CalcPointLight(light, vec3(v_position, 0.0f));

    f_color = vec4(result, 1.0) * texture(u_texture, v_uv);
```

it has a dot in a middle of the light which I HATE! (the dot disappears when `z` position of the light is `0` [also not always, sometimes light just does not work], it looks weird, though), my scene gets darker and darker, when the first screenshot has this "max" darkness value and it overall my light does not look at all as cool as the screen above.

[image]

whole shader

```cpp
#version 460 core

out vec2 v_uv;
out vec2 v_position;

vec4 position[4] = {
    vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};

void main()
{
    v_uv = position[gl_VertexID].zw;
    v_position = position[gl_VertexID].xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position[gl_VertexID].xy, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

```cpp
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 f_color;

in vec2 v_uv;
in vec2 v_position;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;  

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
};

PointLight pointLights[4];

vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 fragPos)
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + 
                 light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient;
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff;

    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;

    return ambient + diffuse;
} 

void main()
{        
    PointLight light;
    light.position = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.005f);
    light.constant = 1.0f;
    light.linear = 0.09f;
    light.quadratic = 0.032f;
    light.ambient = vec3(0.1f);
    light.diffuse = vec3(0.8f);

    vec3 result = CalcPointLight(light, vec3(v_position, 0.0f));

    light.position = vec3(-0.5f, 0.7f, 0.005f);
    light.constant = 0.5f;
    light.linear = 0.09f;
    light.quadratic = 0.032f;
    light.ambient = vec3(0.1f);
    light.diffuse = vec3(0.8f);

   // result += CalcPointLight(light, vec3(v_position, 0.0f));

    light.position = vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.00f);
    light.constant = 1.0f;
    light.linear = 0.09f;
    light.quadratic = 0.032f;
    light.ambient = vec3(0.1f);
    light.diffuse = vec3(0.8f);

   // result += CalcPointLight(light, vec3(v_position, 0.0f));

    f_color = vec4(result, 1.0) * texture(u_texture, v_uv);
}
```

How can I achieve an effect shown in the first photo?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"it does not look good at all"*? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I did explain. Just look at the first photo and my photos. That's the first point. The second point is THE DOT!, the third point, my light gets darker and darker, the first photo has some max range. At the first glance the first scene light looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `smoothstep`, something like:

```
gl_FragColor = smoothstep( yourFinalColour, vec3( 0 ), length( yourLight, uv );
```